# Is there a termination character for bq in interactive mode? How do I set it?

Tags: google-bigquery

I've just started using bigquery and I'm used to writing SQL across multiple lines.  However, if I run

```
bq shell
```

to get into interactive mode, I can't put a query in that runs across multiple lines without bq reporting an error, as it evaluates the first line of the instruction and then complains there's no FROM or GROUP BY clauses.

In other database clients, I can set a termination character: eg in DB2,

```
db2 -t
```

allows me to run db2 with commands terminated with ;

Is there a way to run bq with a termination character for each statement?  I've looked at https://developers.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool and although it refers to global flags, I don't see a reference to termination characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After delving in the [source code for bq](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery-tools/source/checkout), I can confirm there's not such termination character that allows you to do multi-line queries.

It's a consequence of the [cmd](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html) module on which bq shell is built upon.

As an alternative you could run queries directly from your shell with bq query YOUR QUERY as the shell allows multi-line commands when enclosed in double quotes (").

Example:

```
bq query "SELECT station_number, year, month, day 
FROM [publicdata:samples.gsod]
LIMIT 10"

+----------------+------+-------+-----+
| station_number | year | month | day |
+----------------+------+-------+-----+
|          42420 | 2007 |     5 |  20 |
|          42080 | 2007 |     5 |   5 |
|         152990 | 1990 |     3 |  26 |
|         543110 | 1976 |    10 |  24 |
|         740430 | 1966 |    11 |  30 |
|         228540 | 1949 |     9 |  23 |
|         747809 | 2009 |     7 |  17 |
|         681120 | 1997 |     2 |  15 |
|          26070 | 2008 |    12 |  27 |
|         128430 | 1988 |     9 |  22 |
+----------------+------+-------+-----+
```